# Python - Read a text file and search for all occurrences of a substring

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

I am reading in a large text file and want to search for all occurrences of four substrings. When a substring is found I want to output the full string that contained the substring.

Have tried beautiful soup and find function in python.

Comment: Can you pleasse [edit] your question and put there example input and expected output?